# Rx - Scheduler that only allows n number of parallel operations at a time

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to write a [Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229149(v=vs.103)) that allows Limited Concurrency. Here is what I have written.

```
public class ThreeAtATimeScheduler : IScheduler
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(3);

public IDisposable Schedule<TState>(TState state, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable> action)
{
    var scheduler = ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance;
    return new CompositeDisposable(
        Disposable.Create(() => _semaphore.Release()),
        _semaphore.WaitAsync().
        ContinueWith(t => scheduler.Schedule(state, action))
    );
 }

...
}
```

And here is how I am trying to use it (In my use case I have to accumulate some messages before I can start working on a batch).

```
var scheduler = new ThreeAtATimeScheduler();
var subscription = 
Observable.Range(0, 100)
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 10)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .Select(x => Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Performing for Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    }, scheduler))
    .Concat()
    .Subscribe();
```

My program shows the following output and ends after a few seconds.

```
Performing for Thread 3
Performing for Thread 5
Performing for Thread 8
```

I debugged and found that none of the Semaphores are being released ever.

If there is a better way to write this scheduler, I would love to find out about it but I would also love to find out why mine isn't working.

My guess is that the Dispose has to be called explicitly on the returned Disposable but the [Observable.Start() implementation discards your disposable and returns it's own Empty one](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Concurrency/Scheduler.Simple.cs#L61C1-L61C39), and the Garbage Collector never calls Dispose, hence Release never happens.

Answer (score 1):

**Old answer**

As for me, you do not need the custom scheduler here. You can limit the concurrency purely by Rx linq methods like this:

```
        Observable.Range(0, 100)
            .Buffer(10)
            .Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(() =>Task.Run(()=>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Performing for Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                return x.Sum();
            })))
            .Merge(3) // <-- degree of parallelism
            .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The example shows the sum calculated from input buffers.

Then you can wrap `.Select.Merge` into your own extension method which accepts the lambda and degree of parallelism:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Parallel<TSource, TResult>(this IObservable<TSource> input, Func<TSource, TResult> selector, int degreeOfParallelism) =>
    input
        .Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Run(()=>selector(x))))
        .Merge(degreeOfParallelism);

static void Main()
{
  Observable.Range(0, 100)
    .Buffer(10)
    .Parallel(x =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Performing for Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
      return x.Sum();
    }, 3)
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: It works, great idea. But it only controls the concurrency at subscription level, not the entire app domain. If I had an scheduler, I could use the singleton of it in all my subscriptions.

Comment: @fahadash please check my fresh answer, probably it is closer to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach with the semaphore as a gate. So you still need no custom scheduler, but the shared semaphore instance only.

*Note that this is still not a robust solution, but PoC - it can have a semaphore slot leak if unsubscribed at certain times.*

```
   public static IObservable<TResult> Parallel<TSource, TResult>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
   {
        var gate = Observable
            .Never<Unit>()
            .StartWith(Unit.Default)
            .Do(_ => semaphore.Wait())
            .Finally(() => semaphore.Release())
            .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Immediate)
            .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Immediate);

       return source
           .Select(x =>
           {
               var gated = gate.Subscribe();
               return (x, gated);
           })
           .Select(x => Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Run(() =>
           {
               try
               {
                   return selector(x.x);
               }
               finally
               {
                   x.gated.Dispose();
               }
           })))
           .Merge();
   }


    static void Main()
    {
        SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(3);


        Observable
            .Range(0, 1000000)
            .Buffer(10)
            .Parallel(x =>
            {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Performing on Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, Semaphore state: {_semaphore.CurrentCount}");
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    return x.Sum();
            }, _semaphore)
            .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```